# How to identify the reason why an HTML Div changes color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the beginning I used chrome to Break on the "click" event but then I realized then even disabling JS the color change still happens.

So, now I think it's something happening related to JS. But I have one div with insid some span and CSS selector can make my life hard.

How can I intercept a CSS rule that becomes used just for the time I click a button?

Comment: In Chrome, if you inspect the element it gives you a stack of the css rules that have been applied to the element.  Rules that have been overridden by other rules are struck through - this might help identify which rule has applied a different colour

Comment: Do you have an example page that we can see?

Comment: @thePav: no... but at the end I've found my mistake. I was trying to force the :active on a child element and the css active rule was defined for the parent

Comment: @Revious, Ah yes, that will do it. +1

Answer (score 2):

> How can I intercept a CSS rule that becomes used just for the time I click a button?

Use any developer tools, inspect divs and see what rule are applied to it.

You can even try several pseudoselectors from DevTools.

[image: Example here]

Comment: I've solved in this way at the end.. but isn't there a way to "listen" to the applied CSS?

Comment: the docs for that feature: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#force-element-state